# Exclude related model data on the fly in Yii

Tags: php, yii

is it possible to exclude related model data from a find condition on the fly?

I have a Post model that HAS_MANY Images and I do a findByPK($id) it loads both Post and Images model that is related to Post at the same time.

How do I exclude these related model it on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not actually loading anything, Yii uses lazy loading by default. that is it only loads related models on request. so:

```
$post = Post::model()->findByPK($id);
//At this point images are not yet loaded

When you call the images, Yii notices they are not loaded and loads them
$post->images;
```

That means, your images are not loaded unless you need them.